# How can I get a process's variable adress in memory in Linux?

Tags: linux

In a game, I need to retrieve the adress for the character's Coins.

I tried to follow the memory address I want using GDB and GameConqueror but I was always unsuccessful. 
I tried using LD_preload and compare the size returned but sometimes the sizes of the memory I want changes so I don't think I can use that (or I really don't know what I am doing, also a possible explanation).
Is this possible at all?

Comment: How is this question related to Python? And why exactly do you need the memory address?

Comment: Sorry. It should be only Linux related. I was about to say a few things I tried on the side with python but I found out to be kinda irrelevant. I need the address so I can read the number of Coins the character has.

Comment: Sorry, not a programming code Q. Please read [help on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.